# Installed Ubuntu on HDD, how to move it partially onto SSD

Tags: 14.04, ssd

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 entirely on the HDD of my Dell Inspiron 14z which has 500GB HDD + 32 GB SSD. I have 24GB of SSD lying unused and I would like to allocate about 18GB of the SSD to Ubuntu. Please tell me what is an efficient method for doing it and what specific directories(such as home, tmp or boot ) can I move onto the SSD and what can be kept on HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your place I would make it like this:

1. Install the system on the SSD,
2. Keep the /home mounted on the HDD

The fstab's relevant rows would look something like this:

```
/dev/sda1       /         ext4     noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0       1 
/dev/sdb1       /home     ext4     noatime,nodiratime,defaults          0       2
```

Comment: Would that be possible (although perhaps not recommended) without a reinstall? Copying over the whole directory tree (without /home), then changing fstab and rebooting?

Comment: Well, I have done something similar when moving from a smaller HDD to a bigger using: `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb`. It took some time. After that I've booted from a live CD, I've resized the partitions with `gparted`, chrooted to the HDD, issued `sudo update-grub2`, and rebooted to the fitted new disk.

Comment: @Frantique I am new to dealing with partitions can u plz give a more detailed explanation as to what I can do. I am ready to reinstall considering that I installed Ubuntu only today. Can you even tell me what all should i shift and corresponding commands (inconvenience regretted)

Comment: See here: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installseparatehome

Comment: @Frantique -> thanx for link. Followed it and allotted 10GB of SSD fot /home and rest is on HDD but not able to recognize or use the HDD's 15 GB allotted :( Some help?

Comment: @9shank4: can you post the content of /etc/fstab and the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: sudo fdisk -l ->  http://pastebin.com/hstmJZXm
/etc/fstab -> http://pastebin.com/yUJgWcZE